# Sencha Touch: AutoScroll not working in DataView

Tags: scroll, sencha-touch

I have a DataView that is always displaying the scroller, I need the scroller to work only when the content exceeds the height of the screen. I tried setting the property of autoScroll but it didn't work. Is there another way?

This is the code of the data view:

```
  this.dataView = new Ext.DataView({
        store: myStore, 
        autoScroll: true,
        tpl: tpl
  });
```

if I set scroll to horizontal or scroll to false, it does respond to the command. Even though it doesn't say anything about it on the documentation http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.view.View

Is there another way to set the scroller to appear only when necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by setting the height to 100% in the CSS